# How to send a file in skype to a particular skype user using Java Application?

Tags: java, file, share, skype, skype4java

I want to share a normal file(.pdf, or .doc) to a particular skype user using Java Application. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Here you go http://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet for sending a file to a particular user using Java program?

Comment: You need to put some effort into this and then you can share your problem with everyone here(if it doesn't work). This site is not for giving the whole solution without putting in any efforts